# How should it be interpreted?

Tags: word-meaning

Human civilization is transformed to a ‘quasi nature’, aiming to correct and replace nature.

(Source: The self-criticism of Science by Alexis Karpouzos from Athens Greece)

I have two questions to ask.

■Who is aiming to correct and replace nature, human civilization or a quasi nature?
As far as the verb replace is concerned, my understanding is that human civilization is aiming to replace nature with a quasi nature, isn't it?

■How should the word "aiming" be interpreted in relation to your answer to the first question above?
These are the possible interpretations I came up with.
(1) Human civilization is transformed to a ‘quasi nature’ WHILE (human civilization is) aiming to correct and replace nature (with a quasi nature)
(2) Human civilization is transformed to a ‘quasi nature’ AND (human civilization) aims to correct and replace nature.
Which interpretation of the two is correct?

Could you help me clarify it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to disagree, but to me "aiming to correct and replace nature" is a reduced relative clause whose referent is "a 'quasi nature'": *...a quasi nature, which aims to correct and replace nature*. Hardly can human civilization aim to replace nature if it is the subject of a passive verb, which denotes an involuntary process. The same woulld apply if "become" were used. For human civilization to be the actual doer of the action, there should be a verb like "adopts": *Human civilization adopts a quasi nature, and in doing so it aims to correct and replace nature* (notice the change of meaning).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.    How about the verb "to correct"?   I just don't get how on earth the phrase "a quasi nature" could possibly CORRECT nature.  How is that possible? It really doesn't make sense.   Passive voice cannot be a determiner of whether aiming is participle or clause.   I think aiming is participle and its subject is himan civilization.

Comment: This sentence is highly controversial and very poorly worded. The only person likely to have any idea what it is supposed to mean is the author.

Comment: @DeborahJeong Passive voice shows that the subject is the recipient of the action. The present participle needs to have another subject. As I see it, by "quasi nature" the author means a system with its own rules, one that is established to correct those rules that are found to be unfair or in any way undesirable in nature.